# Is it possible to check which query takes more time in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if i execute 500 query at a time in mysql, for all this some of query takes a lot time, so i want to know which query taken more time to execute in descending order.Is it possible to check ? Or any one have better idea for this ?

Comment: Thanks to all for great help